# PHP something not working with session on mobile

Tags: php

I've got a login form that creates a session named "member" with the user's id when it successfully logs in. then on each page, I will have

```
if(!isset($_SESSION["member"]) || empty($_SESSION["member"])) {
header("Location: http://www.website.com/login");
die();
} else {
show page
}
```

this works fine on laptops and desktops but when I log in via mobile or tab, it will only bring me to the menu page. any other links i click on the menu page will result in it redirecting me back to the login page. I've tried about 20 times over a few days and only managed to log in 3 times

what seems to be the problem?

also, at the moment I only kill the session when the user clicks logout. is it ok? or should I have something to calculate inactivity? (if user is inactive for 30 minutes, session timeout) if so, will the script be enough if I just have it on the menu page or would it have to be on every page? Thanks

Comment: first off, you don't need `!isset` and `empty`, `empty` is like a combination of both `!isset` and checking if it's not `null`

Comment: @Gerton, I often combine `isset` and `empty` as just checking for `empty` results in an error if the variable being checked isn't set. However, I don't think it should be an `&&` operator, you should if it isset OR if it's NULL.

Comment: Have you tried a different mobile device or browser? Could be a problem with the cookies that invalidates the session.

Comment: @geoffAtkins I see your point. i'll change it.

Comment: @jeroen I've tried a few mobile devices running android 2.2 - 4.4. what do you mean by cookies that invalidates the session?

Comment: If there is no cookie or query string in the url, the server can't connect the session to the request.

Comment: basically I add the user's id as session "member" and I check with the code on every page. would there be room for error on this part?